# Test several observables in order

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to do some kind of try-and-error approach. I have several observables and I want to take the value of the first observable, which didn't run into error. What I tried:

```
const err1$ = throwError('err1');
const err2$ = throwError('err2');
const ok1$ = of('ok1').pipe(tap(x => console.log('hot ok1')));
const ok2$ = of('ok2').pipe(tap(x => console.log('hot ok2')));
const ok3$ = of('ok3').pipe(tap(x => console.log('hot ok3')));

onErrorResumeNext(err1$, err2$, ok1$, ok2$, ok3$).pipe(
  first(),
  defaultIfEmpty('all failed'),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

My problem is, that I don't want to execute `ok2$` and `ok3$`, since `ok1$` was fine, but they become hot with this aproach. My target is, that I only see `hot ok1` (from tap) and `ok1` (from subscription) in the console log https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pmqbcv?file=index.ts

Comment: Your approach works for asynchronous observables. So you're looking for a way to do this synchronously?

Comment: No, in my actual case those are http calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the answer of evilstiefel I now found a working approach with

```
const err1$ = throwError('err1');
const err2$ = throwError('err2');
const ok1$ = of('ok1').pipe(tap(x => console.log('hot ok1')));
const ok2$ = of('ok2').pipe(tap(x => console.log('hot ok2')));
const ok3$ = of('ok3').pipe(tap(x => console.log('hot ok3')));

of(err1$, err2$, ok1$, ok2$, ok3$).pipe(
  map(obs$ => obs$.pipe(catchError(() => of(undefined)))),
  concatAll(),
  filter((val) => val !== undefined),
  first(),
  defaultIfEmpty('all failed'),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-e5bcko?file=index.ts

Comment: Do note that you still need the line `catchError(() => EMPTY),` before your call to `defaultIfEmpty`, otherwise it will never be triggered (it throws an `EmptyError` if you filter everything away).

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want, by wrapping every observable into a pipe which returns undefined on Error (`catchDefaultConcat`). Afterwards we can filter away any erroneous results (which would be problematic if `undefined` is a valid result for an observable).

It's an interesting problem, and the docs of `onErrorResumeNext` say that it basically just concatenates the source observables and "swallows" errors, but I'm also unsure as to why it doesn't unsubscribe when you hit your `first()` call.

```js
const err1$ = throwError('err1');
const err2$ = throwError('err2');
const ok1$ = of('ok1').pipe(tap(x => console.log('hot ok1')));
const ok2$ = of('ok2').pipe(tap(x => console.log('hot ok2')));
const ok3$ = of('ok3').pipe(tap(x => console.log('hot ok3')));

const catchDefaultConcat = (...args: Observable<any>[]) => {
  return concat(args.map((arg) => arg.pipe(
    catchError(() => of(undefined))
  )));
}

catchDefaultConcat(err1$, err2$, ok1$, ok2$, ok3$).pipe(
  concatAll(),
  filter((val) => val !== undefined),
  first(),
  catchError(() => EMPTY),
  defaultIfEmpty('all failed'),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: That prints an error for the last pipe `Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.`

Comment: You inspired me to find a working approach, I added it as another answer.

Comment: It worked on Stackblitz, I had a feeling though that it was maybe unnecessarily complicated ;). Your version is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

In RxJs 6 the `onErrorResumeNext` approach fails for synchronous Observables but works for asynchronous Observables. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-7jxjwh?file=index.ts

In RxJs 7 this was [fixed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/5650) and the `onErrorResumeNext` approach works for all Observables. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-y98evs?file=index.ts

---

`onErrorResumeNext` is currently [considered for deprecation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5645#issuecomment-681110496) so a replacement with `concat` and `catchError` is probably the best option.

```ts
function concatCatching(...args: ObservableInput<any>[]): Observable<any> {
  return concat(...args.map(o => from(o).pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY))))
}
```

```ts
concatCatching(err1$, err2$, ok1$, ok2$, ok3$).pipe(
  take(1),
  defaultIfEmpty('all failed'),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fd1qyp?file=index.ts

Comment: I see, the delay(0) is changing the behavior here. Can you explain why?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm As I understand it `onErrorResumeNext` subscribes directly to the next source if the previous completed without checking if the destination is closed. And the unsubscribe from the source of `take(1)` only happens after all previous synchronous actions are done. The `delay(0)` moves the execution to the next event loop iteration so the late unsubscribe is not a problem then. This problem is fixed in RxJs 7 btw: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/5650